# Why is ZFC used more widely than NBG?

Tags: mathematical-logic, set-theory

In studying the solutions proposed for Russell's Paradox on naive set theory (mainly [the corresponding entry in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/)) I came across the following considerations:
von Neumann theory of class solves Russell's Paradox as does Zermelo's solution, but with the advantage of treating directly proper classes.

My question then is why Zermelo's solution (or precisely Zermelo-Frankel + axiom of choice) still more widely used (to my knowledge) than von Neumann-Bernay-Gödel's?

I was told it is an historical accident, but I am not sure if it is only the period of discovery that made ZFC stick as grounding of set theory or if there are other reasons.

Comment: It is not a historical accident, and the issue is addressed on Math. SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136215/difference-between-zfc-nbg